# TeX macro/primitive vs Plain TeX macro

Tags: macros, formatting, tex-core, plain-tex, primitives

I know there are TeX primitives and Plain TeX macros created (directly/indirectly) by TeX primitives. My question is are there TeX macro?
E. g. I can use `\break` in pdfTeX without defining it and `\break` is not a TeX primitive.
Is it a TeX macro or a Plain TeX macro?
Plain TeX is a format like LaTeX.
Does the TeX engine load Plain TeX by default? If not `\break` must be a TeX macro.

Comment: There are primitives, and there are macros: how we 'call' the latter is something of a semantic issue. For example, LaTeX defines `\centerline` as in plain TeX, but it's not a documented part of LaTeX ...

Comment: *Does the TeX engine load Plain TeX by default?* — yes if you invoke it as `tex` or `pdftex` (in a typical TeX distribution), it does load plain TeX by default (you should see something like “preloaded format=pdftex” or “preloaded format=tex” in the first line of the program output, which are both references to plain).

Answer (score 3):

When TeX starts, it does not know a single macro, only primitives. If it runs as iniTeX, it expects to be given a file to execute (or you could enter commands interactively), and that file could (and for sure, *will*) define a bunch of macros. If it does not run as iniTeX, it expects to be told the name of a format file, which will also contain a bunch of macro definitions, among other things. (Normally, TeX looks at the name it is being called by to figure out what format to load.) By the way, a format file is nothing but a binary representation of the internal state of iniTeX before it executed a `\dump` primitive.

In particular, no, TeX does not load the plain macros by default, and no, there are no “TeX macros” the way you think there are, if I understood you correctly.

However, the LaTeX format does contain the vast majority of plain TeX macros, sometimes unchanged, sometimes in modified form.

Comment: When I execute pdfTeX (miktex-pdftex.exe) I can use `\break` macro and as the TeXbook say `\break` is a plain TeX macro. How does miktex-pdftex.exe know to load Plain TeX? Why are Plain TeX macro available without explicitly being loaded? The only argument of miktex-pdftex.exe is `$fullname``.

Comment: +1, but "TeX does not load the plain macros by default" might be correct in theory, although in practice the user will call something like "pdftex" which preloads plain.

Comment: @Johnwebner Simply start pdftex without any argument, you will drop into interactive mode and have something like `preloaded format=pdftex` in the first few lines.

Comment: As I said in my answer, if it does not run as iniTeX, it will typically look at the name it is being run as (for example, `pdftex` or `miktex-pdftex.exe`, apparently), and use that information to decide what preloaded format to load. You can override that with the command line option `-fmt=…`, naming the format to be loaded.

Comment: The point made by @TeXnician (and I agree) is that statements like “When TeX starts, it does not know a single macro…” and “TeX does not load the plain macro by default” are rather misleading, because “by default” one invokes TeX as `tex` or `pdftex` or something like that; it's the `-ini` form (INITEX) that is rare and unusual (i.e., not the default) — calling INITEX the default is a very unconventional usage of “default” IMO; even Knuth's original design had “TEX” like present-day `tex` (called the “production version of TeX” in the TeX program source code), and “INITEX” was special.

Comment: Well, my statement is certainly not *wrong*, but I admit it may mislead. It has to be read in the context of your answer, however, and *in that context* I don't think it is misleading: TeX really does not know a single macro when it starts. Not until it has loaded a format file, that is. It is true that it will do so in the majority of situations. I certainly did not intend to state that iniTeX is the more common usage! The most common is probably `pdflatex`, though, which does *not* load plain; it loads the latex format, which contains a modified version of plain. (@TeXnician)